How to show a list of lists that contain lists with unknown field names?
I'm new to using Flutter and have to make a model class for a weirdly structured API that I can't seem to find any solutions for within the documentation or anywhere online.
Here's how the JSON file is structured
{
    "series_values": {
        "card_1": {
            "card_series": {
                "Playername": "SAMPLE NAME",
                "cardnumber": "999",
             }
        }
        "card_2": {
            "card_series": {
                "Playername": "SAMPLE NAME",
                "cardnumber": "999",
             }
        }
    }
}


The main issue is that I don't know what the name of the elements within series_values are going to be titled nor do I know how many will be in the list(card_1 and card_2 are just sample names), but I know that they will always be a list that contains card_series that contains Playername and cardnumber. How would I design a class to get the data from the JSON for each one?
I've made a model file to read the JSON file, but I have no idea how to make it put the card_series list inside each item in the series_values list.
class CardSeries {
  final String playername;
  final String cardnumber;

  CardSeries({required this.cardnumber, required this.playername});

  factory CardSeries.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return CardSeries(
      playername: json['Playername'],
      cardnumber: json['cardnumber'],
    );
  }
}



class CardSV {
  final List<CardSeries> cs;

  CardSV({required this.cs});

  factory CardSV.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return CardSV(
      cs: List<CardSeries>.from(json['card_series'].map((cs) => CardSeries.fromJson(cs)),
      )
    );
  }
}


class SeriesValues {
  final List<CardSV> cardsSV;

  SeriesValues({required this.cardsSV});

  ???
  }
}

class CardInfo {
  final List<SeriesValues> seriesValues;

  CardInfo({required this.seriesValues});

  factory CardInfo.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return CardInfo(
      seriesValues: List<SeriesValues>.from(json['series_Values'].map((seriesValues) => SeriesValues.fromJson(seriesValues)),)
    );
  }
}


Based on your json. Your "card_series" is not in a list, But you said: "but I know that they will always be a list that contains card_series that contains Playername and cardnumber". Update your question accordingly.
